# how to query database and show information in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Patient` database entity.
i would like to query and check if a `Patient` record already exists using a given `id`.

the result (such as *`that id already exists`*) should be stored in **`textBox1`** and presented to the user.

This is what i've got so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace LMS {
    public partial class PIDD: Form {
        public PIDD() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            this.Close();
            frmMed Med = new frmMed();
            Med.Show();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }
    }
}
```

How should I continue from this point?

Comment: Welcome, you need to add more info. like which database in use (mysql, sqlserver, sqlite, ... )? and if an ORM is in use (entityframework , custom, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mssql,try this.

```
            var connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
            connection.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM Table WHERE id='" + textBox2.Text + "",connection);
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = reader["id"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                ///No entry found
            }
            connection.Close();
```